# Print footer only in last printed page for media print

Tags: css, printing

I need to print multiple pages and footer needs to be print in last page bottom. I have add css for footer like this

```
footer {
     display: block;
     width:100%;        
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     bottom:0px;        
}
```

Issue is footer is printing first page, but i need this on last page.

Answer (score 0):

Include a stylesheet with your custom style for footer for print using `media="print"` as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourpath/footerstyle.css" media="print"/>
```

or

embed styles as in html

```
<style>
@media print {
   footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;        
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;        
   }
}
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    footer {
        display: block;
        width:100%;        
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;         
    }
</style>
```

Try to position the body relative and the footer absolute:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
     body {
        position: relative;
     }
     footer {
        display: block;
        width:100%;        
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;         
     }
</style>
```

or you could use something like this:

```
@page:last {
    @bottom-center {
        content: "…";
    }
}
```

[CSS 3 Paged Media module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)

Edit

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
     body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
     }
     .page-section {

        /* Specify physical size of page, margins may vary by browser */

        height: 10 in; /* or give size as per proper calculation of the height of all your pages after which you want footer */
        position: relative;
     }
     footer {
        display: block;
        width:100%;        
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;         
     }
</style>
```

add `.page-section` to relevant div / divs as per you want divs to print per page or directly add to `body` tag.

Comment: above style i have added inside media style only

Comment: media="print" is what is important

Comment: Thanks for your time. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print"> i have added all print related styles inside this

Comment: if content is more than one page then we need footer should move last page bottom. but as per this style footer coming first page bottom.

Comment: page:last {
    @bottom-center {
        content: "…";
    }
} how can i include footer element here ?

Comment: page:last { bottom-center { content: "…"; } }, this will help only to add content:"", for example if you use it as it is as page:last { @bottom-center { content: "This is footer"; } }, you will get "This is footer" at the bottom of last page.
I made an edit try it.