# Print footer element only on the last page at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, printing, footer

I am building a web page that can print a div element. What I cannot seems to found the solution is how to make some div element inside to appear **at the bottom of the page only on the last page**.

Have found multiple answers that said it is not possible, but dated to around 2015. Are there still no solution for this issue?

here is the link for reference:

- [Print table footer at the very bottom on last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448846/print-table-footer-at-the-very-bottom-on-last-page)
- [Footer on last printed page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176770/footer-on-last-printed-page)
- [Print footer only in last printed page for media print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242019/print-footer-only-in-last-printed-page-for-media-print/35012256)

The other solution said they works because they do not need to print the footer at the bottom of the last page.

Currently, I am using this code.

```
@media print {
   #footer {
       position : fixed;
       bottom : 0;
   }
}
```

It can place the footer at the bottom. But the issue is it will be repeated for every page. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would seem pretty easy to write some JS logic to select the div you want to print, and insert the footer at the end of it, given the info here: https://coderwall.com/p/c5xzpw/printing-the-contents-of-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: yes it was relatively easy to write some JS logic just to print the div and for the footer div to appear you can use media print. But what is needed is for that div to only appear at the bottom of the last page (for multiple pages).

Comment: Right, but I wouldn't even bother with media print.  I would just duplicate the footer and append it to the div you're printing.  That way, it will always be on the last page.

Comment: yes, but it will not stay at the bottom. I need the div to have a footer behaviour for the last page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in plain js. This solutions prints "Print my page" on the last page using `page-break-after: always` on the rest of your content.

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zgk3s9x/1/) or code below:

```
    <div id="content">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec turpis varius, pellentesque velit pellentesque, ullamcorper eros. Ut nec nunc facilisis, lobortis felis in, varius sapien. Maecenas nec nulla et quam pellentesque eleifend. Nullam tempus tellus sed lacinia molestie. Fusce pharetra dui eu neque sollicitudin, id bibendum sapien consequat. Proin fringilla turpis a nunc tristique varius. Vivamus vehicula ipsum ex, sed lobortis ligula viverra eu. Duis vestibulum in risus non commodo. Proin non quam quam. Nulla porttitor scelerisque volutpat.
      </p>
      <p>
      Mauris in congue diam, in fringilla risus. Nullam dolor ligula, porttitor sed neque at, vestibulum aliquam risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In quis convallis enim. Curabitur sit amet efficitur ante. Aenean ante libero, volutpat sit amet viverra non, pellentesque iaculis felis. Ut ut convallis nisl. Phasellus maximus nisl non consectetur efficitur. Aliquam hendrerit lacus sit amet sagittis vestibulum. Sed maximus luctus leo, fermentum interdum nisl malesuada quis. Ut porttitor in nisl at molestie. Vivamus aliquam eros sem, at viverra turpis venenatis eget. Donec hendrerit leo velit, a scelerisque nunc varius sit amet. Ut dignissim tincidunt justo, tempus commodo erat.
      </p>
      <p>
      Nunc commodo lobortis leo, non vulputate magna. Ut arcu nunc, hendrerit quis mattis a, aliquet vel sem. Donec vel lacus sit amet ipsum dapibus eleifend. Duis sit amet nulla velit. Integer rutrum turpis porttitor felis dignissim, vitae vulputate mauris feugiat. In aliquam eu eros id imperdiet. Etiam interdum sit amet ligula non scelerisque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur in consectetur mauris. Donec elementum lobortis fringilla. Morbi porttitor, nisi id tincidunt hendrerit, risus risus feugiat mauris, ut ornare nunc nunc ut ante. Donec quis arcu rhoncus, auctor elit eget, lacinia erat. Duis ornare molestie massa nec elementum.
      </p>
      <p>
      Nam hendrerit rutrum nisi sed eleifend. Sed vehicula ultrices augue, nec interdum lorem commodo a. Nullam eget suscipit tortor, ut ultrices justo. Curabitur varius, magna non ullamcorper lacinia, risus lorem finibus enim, sed sagittis quam nisl sit amet ipsum. Nulla ac pulvinar lacus. Vivamus dapibus leo a erat aliquet placerat. Donec facilisis lectus id magna posuere, quis condimentum eros commodo. Vestibulum posuere nisi tortor, sit amet euismod sapien lacinia vitae.
      </p>
      <p>
      Donec facilisis, nisi id vestibulum feugiat, neque leo suscipit justo, nec interdum dolor urna nec leo. In ultricies aliquet auctor. Sed sollicitudin ante felis, ut tempor velit imperdiet eget. Pellentesque in ligula aliquet justo ornare lobortis. Morbi dapibus augue non pretium malesuada. Sed ultrices elit risus, at ullamcorper eros dignissim in. Morbi convallis augue ac ex laoreet sagittis.
      </p>
    </div>
    <button onclick="OpenPrintPage()">
    Print My Page
    </button>
    <script>
            function OpenPrintPage() {

                var OriginalContent = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
                var PrintWindow =   window.open("","PrinterFriendlyPage","scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,height=510,width=750"); 

                PrintWindow.document.write( '<html><head><style>#content {page-break-after: always;}</style></head><body><div id="' + 'content' + '">' + '</div><a class="printbtn" href="javascript:window.print()">{ Print This Page }</a></body></html>'); 

                PrintWindow.document.close(); 
                PrintWindow.document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += OriginalContent; 
            }


    </script>
```

Comment: this fiddle will print "print my page" at the top of the last page and will also insert a page break so will leave an empty page at the end. What i mean is i need the "print my page" button to appear at the bottom of the page.

Comment: So for example, if it has 2 pages then it will appear at the bottom of the second page but not the first page.